# Лишние пробелы в конечном .txt Java

Tags: java, строки

Понапихал этих условий в строку, на проверку что содержит строка и т.д. ибо без этого не работает программа. Теперь же, в результате алгоритма почему то между символами добавляется лишний пробел но программа работает всегда корректно, пробелы легко можно убрать в блокноте, но почему они добавляются? даже .replace(" ", "") не помогает

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(saving_adrs).getAbsoluteFile());
    try {
        for (int i=0; i<=count_of_elements; i ++ ) {
            String dno = linesAsArray[i];
            if (dno.isEmpty()) {
            }
            else {
                if (dno.contains(":")) {
                    String[] parts = dno.split(slasher);
                    String part1 = parts[0]; // logins
                    String part2 = parts[1]; // passwords 
                    if (part1.isEmpty() || part2.isEmpty()) {
                    }
                    else {
                        String analys = part2.toLowerCase();
                        if (analys != part2) {
                            out.println(dno.replace(" ", ""));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можно у тебя файл в кодировке, которая добавяет какие-то маркеры типа BOM, попробуй указать кодировку сам или проверить (поменяй файл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то я не пойму зачем Вы режете строку, а потом все равно записываете в файла  входную строку(удаляя пробелы) в файл вместе с разделителем.
Только что проверил, все работает. Вот код мой если что. На выходе получаем строку

> loginpassword

в данном случае.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     final String slasher = ":";
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new File("/home/crosp/test.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

                    String dno = "login:password";
                    if (dno.isEmpty()) {
                    }
                    else {
                        if (dno.contains(":")) {
                            String[] parts = dno.split(slasher);
                            String part1 = parts[0]; // logins
                            String part2 = parts[1]; // passwords
                            if (part1.isEmpty() || part2.isEmpty()) {
                            }
                            else {
                                String analys = part2.toLowerCase();
                                if (analys != part2) {
                                    out.println(dno.replace(" ", "")); // Удаляете пробелы из входной строки ?? Сравниваете part2 ?
                                }
                            }
                            out.print(part1);
                            out.print(part2);
                            out.flush();

                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //NOP
            }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```